# Beginner Java do while concept confusion

Tags: java, do-while

My logic is the output will keep the order (1,0)(2,1)...(5.4), but the output is (5,5) not (5,4).

Do I misunderstand the do while concepts?

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    do{
        y++;
        ++x;
    } while(x<5);
    System.out.print(x + "," + y);


  }
}
```

Comment: *Why* would you expect (5,4)?

Comment: You increment x and y inside the loop. Then you print their value. Why should y be 4 and not 5?

Comment: Your interpretation of the post increment ooperator is _very_ strange.

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps this is what you where intending?

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    do{
        System.out.println( ++x + "," + y++ );
    } while(x<5);
  }
}
```

Here the value of `x` is incremented before it is passed to the method `println`, so it is always at least one more than the starting value, and increments each iteration.  The value of `y` is incremented *after* it is passed to the method, so it prints first at the starting value, then increases by one each iteration.

(I changed from `print` to `println` because the latter makes the output easier to read.)

---

Lew Bloch pointed out in a comment below that `x` and `y` are not literally being passed to the `println` method.  Instead, the Java compiler actually handles the method by expanding it like this:

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;
      do {
         // System.out.println( ++x + "," + y++ );
         StringBuilder concat = new StringBuilder();
         concat.append( ++x );
         concat.append( ", " );
         concat.append( y++ );        
         System.out.println( concat.toString());
      } while( x < 5 );
   }
```

Instead of actually passing `x` and `y` directly to `println`, Java creates a temporary `StringBuilder` object, which does the string concatenation implied by the code.  Then, the string builder is used to return a string, which is the only thing actually passed to `println`.

However, the `StringBuilder` methods work the same way as described above, so in concept nothing has changed.  `y` is still one less than `x` because the post-increments takes `y`'s value before it is incremented and passes it to the `append` method.  There's very few cases where remembering that a `StringBuilder` object is literally involved that are relevant, though occasionally there can be important speed optimizations you can apply.

Comment: Neither `x` nor `y`'s values are passed to the method. They are operands in an expression. It's the reference to the expression's value that's passed to the method.

Comment: @LewBloch That's fair, to a point.  I think the string concatenation is actually handled by a `StringBuilder`.  So `x` and `y` are literally passed to methods on that object.  I should update my answer.

Comment: The `StringBuilder` is an implementation detail, not a syntactic one. The use of `StringBuilder` is no more required than `StringBuffer` used to be when it was used for string concatenation. What is required is that the expression be fully evaluated before being passed to the method.

Answer (score 1):

If case of code

```
do{
  System.out.print(++x + "," + y++);
} while(x<5);
```

you got expected values (`(1,0)(2,1)...(5.4)`), because in one statement we a) increase x; b) print values; c) increase y.

But in case

```
y++;
++x;
System.out.print(x + "," + y);
```

it doesn't matter, pre- or post- increment is used. On 3rd line both variables are incremented and has the same values.